# Close a modal page via NavigationService

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my **Xamarin.Forms** app I have a **Navigation Service** (based on [Mastering **Xamarin.Forms**](https://github.com/edsnider/mastering-xamarin.forms-book/blob/master/Chapter3/TripLog/TripLog/Services/XamarinFormsNavService.cs)), and I now want to *Push* and *Pop* **Modal Pages**.

So I adopted the `NavigateTo` function from

```cs
public async Task NavigateTo<TVM, TParameter>(TParameter parameter) where TVM : BaseViewModel
{
    await NavigateToView(typeof(TVM));
    
    if (XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel<TParameter>)
    {
       ((BaseViewModel<TParameter>)XamarinFormsNav.NavigationStack.Last().BindingContext).Init(parameter);
    }
}
```

into a new one for **Modal Pages**

```cs
public async Task NavigateToModal<TVM, TParameter>(TParameter parameter) where TVM : BaseViewModel
{
    await NavigateToViewModal(typeof(TVM));
    
    if (XamarinFormsNav.ModalStack.Last().BindingContext is BaseViewModel<TParameter>)
    {
        ((BaseViewModel<TParameter>)XamarinFormsNav.ModalStack.Last().BindingContext).Init(parameter);
    }
}
```

The **Modal Page** is a login form called from `StartPageViewModel` when no login credentials can be found

```
await NavService.NavigateToModal<LoginPageViewModel, LoginData>(loginData);
```

**Page** and **ViewModel** appear and work as expected. But it does not disappear.

The NavigationService method is

```
public void RemoveModalView()
{
    XamarinFormsNav.PopModalAsync(true);
}
```

But nothing happens, the I get the same result when I call `PopModalAsync` from the **ViewModel** of the `Page`.

How can I properly close a **Modal Page**?

Thank you!